# Is it worth learning to touch type

Tags: typing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is touch typing skill important for being a good writer?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/473/is-touch-typing-skill-important-for-being-a-good-writer)

I'm curious about the great novelists, like Kerouac, thompson, hemmingway etc. The ones that had access to typewriters did they touchtype, and is it likely to make more or less mistakes via touch typing? Thanks for any answers I may get, thankyou all.

Comment: why was this question closed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's worth it.  Of course, it depends on how often and how much you type, but for the most part, you'll be happy with the skill.

Not only will you be able to type faster, but you'll be able to keep your eyes on the screen.  This also means that you'll be able to transcribe a lot faster.  Imagine having a large text written out by hand, and constantly having to look back between the paper, keyboard, and screen.  But if you can touch type, your eyes stay on the paper and you trust your fingers to do their job.

As for mistakes and typos, in my experience, there are less to be had with touch typing.  And in the event that you *do* make a mistake, you'll usually feel it right away, and backspacing the right number of characters will quickly become a speedy reflex that you don't even notice.

If you're a writer, and you're on the computer a lot, I definitely recommend learning to touch type.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it really depends on your perspective. I have considered learning touch typing many times, but ultimately I decided I didn't want to commit the time necessary to learn and practice it. I've started a couple of times, but each time I gave up in frustration because I didn't have the patience. If you do have the patience and are willing to commit the time and effort, then it would certainly be worth it in the long run.

Personally, I have gotten to where I type 60-70 wpm, with virtually no mistakes, and I do it all with just two fingers. I don't have to look at the screen because I am confident in my spelling, and even more confident in my spell-checking software! I do a lot of typing at work and at home during my writing, and I find that the more time I spend typing, the less mistakes I make and the faster I go. This is true for just about anything; the more you practice the better you get.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help, I think I have my answer. It's just I'm buying a typewriter, and there's not really a backspace to fix any mistakes, so I was more or less just curious about what others had done before me, and the real benefits of touch typing thanks again for all your help, any additional comments or hellp would be muchly appreciated, thanks, my regards.